# Not able to read the below data as per requirement ( in java script)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

```
bigQuery.query({
    query:'Select email from table',
    useLegacySql: false
}).then(function (rows) {
    setValue(rows);          
});

function setValue(value) {
    someVar = value;
    console.log(someVar);
```

The output in console is this-:

```
[ [ { email: 'v28@gmail.com' },
    { email: 'v29@gmail.com' },
    { email: 'v30@gmail.com' },
    { email: 'v31@gmail.com' } ] ]
```

And i want the output like:

```
v28@gmail.com
v29@gmail.com
v30@gmail.com
v31@gmail.com
```

How to access some `someVar` to get the below output??

Please help me to solve this

Comment: I gave my answer and then deleted it. I don't want to give an answer just for the sake of reputation. I feel like you should really try this. This is a simple for loop. Just try it out. Even if it an incorrect code, put it here and we can guide you.

Comment: `var someVar = value[0].map(function(o) { return o.email; });` or shorter, using an arrow function: `var someVar = value[0].map(o => o.email);`